# No fitted model line for time series segments

Tags: r, time-series, segment

I use the following time series:

```
Lines <- "D1,Value
1,20/11/2014 16:00,0.01
2,20/11/2014 17:00,0.01  
3,20/11/2014 19:00,0.01  
4,20/11/2014 22:00,0.20  
5,20/11/2014 23:00,0.03"

library (zoo)
library (strucchange)

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep = ",")

bp <- breakpoints(z ~ 1, h = 2)

plot(z)
abline(v = time(z)[bp$breakpoints])
```

I would like to add to the graph for each segment the fitted model and in addition to create a dataframe that has the intercept and the slope of the fitted model. 
For the fitted model per segment graph I tried to use the following:

```
lines(z, fitted(bp, breaks = 1), col = 2, lwd = 2)
```

but there is no line. 
For the dataframe I tried to use:

```
coef(bp, breaks = 1)
```

However, I need the slope as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that breakpoints returns a `"ts"` object even if the input is zoo so try this:

```
fit <- zoo(fitted(bp), time(z))
lines(fit, col = "blue", lty = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please add how can I find the plotted models slopes per each segment?

Comment: The two segments are horizontal (no slopes) because the formula specified in the question is `z ~ 1` ..  Using `fit` from the answer, the two levels are `levs <- fit[bp$breakpoints + 0:1]` and the slope per hour between them is `diff(levs) / diff(as.numeric(time(levs)) / 3600)`

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Unfortunately, `breakpoints()` does not cooperate properly with `zoo`. It can consume `zoo` series but essentially treats them like numeric vectors and does not store the corresponding index. I had tried to see whether I can easily squeeze `zoo` support into `breakpoints()` but the changes would not have been trivial and likely not backward compatible. So until now I never got round to writing a much more enhanced new `breakpoints()`...

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I want the slope to be shown for every segment, in case there is no slope - it is 0, how can I update the diff?

Comment: There is no slope, i.e. the slope is 0, since you specified a constant model.